# How to make different objects follow and bend with different curves with AN?

Tags: animation-nodes

how to make each lines to follow each curves as my pic shows?

[image]

Comment: Please search .. Curve Modifier ... here at BSE and other places. Look for tutorials on the website that ryhmes with noonoob.  In my opinion your question is unclear, and can be improved by you.  Yet I took a guess under the cirumstances.  I am not sure why you need AN for this.  Please show any AN you have in screen captures.

Comment: I have 200 different objects, and i need make then to follow 200 different curve as couple.So i need some way to a achieve it.

Comment: Please show your work for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall describe a method to deform an object along a spline. You can extend that to multiple splines/objects using a simple loop.

First, we choose one of the local axis of the target mesh to be the axis along the spline tangent, let that be x in this demonstration. We then get the vertices locations in the local space of the mesh, and normalize the chosen local axis such that it ranges between zero and one, this can be done by remapping it based on the local bounding box, however, for simplicity, we are going to use the value of the x dimensions.

[image: Node Tree]

Then, the normalized x locations are used as the parameters of the spline evaluation process, the tangent and normal are normalized and the cotangent is computed using the cross product. Then, a linear combination of the tangent, normal, and cotangent is computed using the x, y, and z locations of the vertices as the coefficients respectively. Then the evaluated locations are added.

[image: Node Tree]

Finally, a new mesh is constructed from those vertices and output.

[image: Node Tree]